# Safely cast a newtype slice into inner variant without cloning

Tags: rust

Consider the following example
([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c2c63e271860b69993cf58ff83e68229)):

```rust
struct Wrapper(String);

async fn foo(my_slice: &[Wrapper]) {
    bar(my_slice).await; // Error!
}

async fn bar(string_slice: &[String]) { ... }
```

I'm having difficulty writing `foo` such that I can call `bar(my_slice)` without cloning `my_slice`, as `String` doesn't implement `Copy`.

I'm aware of the unsafe method to do this: Put a `#[repr(transparent)]` on `Wrapper` and `mem::transmute` it, but I'm looking for ways to do this in entirely safe Rust.

I've attempted to implement `From`, but slices since are always considered a foreign type and thus I've ran into orphan rules (foreign trait implementation on a foreign type) that prohibit me from doing so.

Unfortunately, I only have the ability to modify `foo` or `Wrapper` as `bar` is auto-generated.

Is there any way to safely cast `&[Wrapper]` to `&[String]` without a clone?

Comment: I would turn functions' arguments into iterators, and used `map` to get inner string. Though whether compiler optimizes it away to just a sequential read of slice is questionable

Comment: Doesn't an iterator from `&[T]` yields a `Iterator<Item = &T>`? I'd still need a clone to get the owned variant, I think, or provide an owned variant (e.g. vec), which would just push the clone to the caller.

Comment: Why would you need to get an owned `String` for your `boo`? The typical pattern is to work with `&str` unless you really need to consume the string

Comment: I agree, but I'm working with generated code. Changing that would be considered a very large breaking change internally, so I'm unable to change this.

I assume we're working with `String`s as we're in an asynchronous context, as a `&str` would need a `'static` lifetime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The type system has no predicate to represent the idea of "can be safely transmuted", so if your type is not one that can be coerced by the compiler itself, you must use `unsafe` to do so.

However, you shouldn't use `transmute` for what is effectively a pointer cast. Instead, decompose the slice into a pointer and a length and make a new slice with the target type.

```
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Wrapper(String);

async fn foo(my_slice: &[Wrapper]) {
    let my_slice =
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(my_slice.as_ptr() as *const String, my_slice.len()) };
    bar(my_slice).await;
}
```

This is slightly more verbose than using `transmute`, but it is also more limited in what it can do. `transmute` is a general purpose tool that requires even more than the usual amount of care; save it for the cases where simple casts don't work.

> I'm looking for ways to do this in entirely safe Rust.

Sticking to safe Rust is often a good idea; however, *never* using `unsafe` means giving up some degree of performance and flexibility in exchange for not having to think too hard in situations like this. This looks like a perfectly fine use of `unsafe` to me: it can be encapsulated in a tiny, safe function and it is easy to prove correct. But if you are determined to avoid `unsafe` then there is no way around `clone`ing the items.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw `from_raw_parts`, but held off in case that there was a safe solution. Do you think something like this could be reasonably part of the stdlib, e.g. through an RFC?

Comment: @xes_p I'm not aware of anything particularly active, but it's been discussed; [here's](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-v2-safe-transmute/11431) a semi-recent thread that you could start from. As simple as it is to verify a trivial case like yours, there are a *lot* of pitfalls that start to appear when you try to think about how to make `transmute` safe more generally. `repr(transparent)`, though necessary, is only one piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Thanks for that link, was definitely an interesting read that I haven't seen before!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in std (looking forward to [safe transmute](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-safe-transmute)) but you can use the [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck) crate to do that safely:

```rust
#[derive(bytemuck::TransparentWrapper)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Wrapper(String);

async fn foo(my_slice: &[Wrapper]) {
    bar(bytemuck::TransparentWrapper::peel_slice(my_slice)).await;
}
```