What is the lowest runtime-overhead way of "naming" a list of tuples in Rust?
I'm getting slightly lost in Rust compiler semantics, but am attempting to find the lowest cost way of simply referring to an array of tuples of numbers by some name for each field and passing that around between functions. More concretely, I am receiving from an external source a list of the form [(f64, f64, f64)], each of which has a name. I want to be able to refer to the fields by name but without converting them to some additional type (unless that is zero cost).
e.g. I could run through and wrap them into:
struct NameStruct {
   foo: f64,
   bar: f64,
   baz: f64,
}

however I presume that would have a cost of running through the array and wrapping them? Whereas a type alias seems like one cannot name individual fields within it.
I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing!

Does this answer your question? How does Rust implement Zero-cost abstraction for NewTypes Pattern

The questions aren't phrased the same. But it's essentially what you're asking

@vallentin: Given that an array is involved, I don’t think that answers the question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76222982/707111? You could also implement a view type wrapping a slice that would probably get optimized away, although that’s a bit verbose and less flexible (you wouldn’t be able to implement IndexMut, for example, without resorting to the same techniques as for the original problem, and would need getters/setters instead).

Is this "external source" a Rust library (that is, you have some function which returns [(f64, f64, f64)], or is this some kind of serialization format?

@Ry- That works for an array or slice, but doesn't for a tuple because tuples are #[repr(Rust)] which means their layout in memory is unspecified.

You can have methods to "name" the fields. Defining methods for all tuples is probably the wrong thing to do, but you can create a #[repr(transparent)] wrapper struct that can be converted in a zero-cost fashion. You can do that with zero unsafe code, as I explained here, via bytemuck:
#[derive(bytemuck::TransparentWrapper)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct NameStruct((f64, f64, f64));

impl NameStruct {
    fn foo(&self) -> f64 { self.0.0 }
    fn bar(&self) -> f64 { self.0.1 }
    fn baz(&self) -> f64 { self.0.2 }
}

fn convert(arr: &[(f64, f64, f64)]) -> &[NameStruct] {
    bytemuck::TransparentWrapper::wrap_slice(arr)
}

